# Dell iDRAC Lifecycle Controller v2.21 - Support TLS 1.2?

Tags: https, dell, tls, drac

Does `Dell iDRAC Lifecycle Controller v2.21` support `TLS 1.2`?

You should be able to (supposing default iDRAC and browser settings), in just a moment, get the answer by pointing your browser to the web interface and then viewing the connection details.  On a box with `openssl` you could alternatively `openssl s_client -connect your.idrac.host -tls1_2`.  If you get the cert chain then it supports 1.2 otherwise it does not.  I would do this myself but don't have the version of interest, v2.21, running.  I also dug through Dell's site for the answer and came up empty handed.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spoke with Dell.  Answer is no.